# Unable to fetch json response into a json array in Jmeter Beanshell Post processor \JSR223 Post processor

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

1. I have below json response array which I am getting into Jmeter Regular expression extractor variable `C_Totalresponse`.
2. In this I have `cartItems` JSON object.
3. In the `cartItems` JSON object, we have different SKUs and corresponding quantities.
4. I'm using a hashmap to read values from a CSV file and update quantity details for each SKU, but my script is failing at fetching response into array in Jmeter.
5. I'm sharing the Jmeter code and error I faced while parsing JSON array at the end

I see many post suggesting groovy I am not sure how to use it for huge response like this

```
[{"statusCode":200,"type":"rpc","tid":7,"ref":true,"action":"ccrz.cc_ctrl_CartRD","method":"fetchMiniCart","result":{"data":{"s":1,"v":{"sfid":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","ownerId":"0058E000005wuxmQAA","sfdcName":"00000563","encryptedId":"b86853d1-2929-44bb-84de-826bb350ff59","activeCart":true,"cartStatus":"Open","cartType":"Cart","lastModifiedDate":1615952024000,"name":"New Cart","effectiveAccountID":"0010Y00001cdP0yQAE","b2BCCTMCCount":1,"b2BCCRYOCount":0,"b2BCCCIGARCount":0,"b2BCCOTHERCount":0,"b2BCCIsEmergency":false,"b2BCCIsOffSchedule":false,"b2BCCIsFlagged":false,"b2BCCProductCount":1,"b2BCCTotalSticks":200,"b2BCCTotalGrams":0,"b2BCCExciseRemainingGrams":199670,"b2BCCExciseRemainingSticks":97800,"b2BCCNumberOfOrdersToday":0,"b2BCCOrderingDate":1615939200000,"b2},"cartItems":{"s":55,"v":[{"s":56,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFa5QAG","sfdcName":"00068652","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":330.53,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":266,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.30,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.50,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFa5QAG","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,},{"s":60,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFa3QAG","sfdcName":"00068650","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":13.00,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":264,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFa3QAG","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":61,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096F3QAI","sfdcName":"WINNIES ROLLING PAPERS 50","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797287227","b2BCCProductCategory":"Other","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000050055946","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":50},"shortDesc":"WINNIES ROLLING PAPERS 50","id":"a6w8E00000096F3QAI","sku":"50055946","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":1.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"BX","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"WINNIES ROLLING PAPERS 50","price":13.00}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096F3QAI","ccrz__SKU__c":"50055946"}}},{"s":62,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFa2QAG","sfdcName":"00068649","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":35.73,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":262,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFa2QAG","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":63,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096EtQAI","sfdcName":"CAPTAIN BLACK DARK CREMA (20) ","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"71737493045","b2BCCProductCategory":"CIGAR","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075002330","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":44},"shortDesc":"CAPTAIN BLACK DARK CREMA (20) ","id":"a6w8E00000096EtQAI","sku":"50050031","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":20.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PK","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"CAPTAIN BLACK DARK CREMA (20) ","price":35.73}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096EtQAI","ccrz__SKU__c":"50050031"}}},{"s":64,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFa1QAG","sfdcName":"00068648","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":35.73,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":261,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFa1QAG","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":65,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096EyQAI","sfdcName":"CAPTAIN BLACK CHERISE (20)","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"71737493076","b2BCCProductCategory":"CIGAR","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075002330","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":47},"shortDesc":"CAPTAIN BLACK CHERISE (20)","id":"a6w8E00000096EyQAI","sku":"50050070","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":20.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PK","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"CAPTAIN BLACK CHERISE (20)","price":35.73}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096EyQAI","ccrz__SKU__c":"50050070"}}},{"s":66,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFa0QAG","sfdcName":"00068647","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":35.73,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":260,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFa0QAG","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":67,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096ACQAY","sfdcName":"CAPTAIN BLACK CLASSIC (20)","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"71737493014","b2BCCProductCategory":"CIGAR","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075002330","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":32},"shortDesc":"CAPTAIN BLACK CLASSIC (20)","id":"a6w8E00000096ACQAY","sku":"50050062","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":20.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PK","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"CAPTAIN BLACK CLASSIC (20)","price":35.73}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096ACQAY","ccrz__SKU__c":"50050062"}}},{"s":68,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZpQAO","sfdcName":"00068636","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":48.49,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":208,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":8.80,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":11.90,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":12.70,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZpQAO","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":69,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000969ZQAQ","sfdcName":"PORT ROYAL 25G RUM & WINE RYO","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797281683","b2BCCProductCategory":"RYO","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075025978","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":29},"shortDesc":"PORT ROYAL 25G RUM &amp; WINE RYO","id":"a6w8E000000969ZQAQ","sku":"10065793","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":25.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PA","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"PORT ROYAL 25G RUM & WINE RYO","price":48.49}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000969ZQAQ","ccrz__SKU__c":"10065793"}}},{"s":70,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZoQAO","sfdcName":"00068635","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":45.22,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":206,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.20,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZoQAO","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":71,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000963wQAA","sfdcName":"PORT ROYAL 25G RAW","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797286466","b2BCCProductCategory":"RYO","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075090737","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":17},"shortDesc":"PORT ROYAL 25G RAW","id":"a6w8E000000963wQAA","sku":"10065785","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":25.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PA","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"PORT ROYAL 25G RAW","price":45.22}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000963wQAA","ccrz__SKU__c":"10065785"}}},{"s":72,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZnQAO","sfdcName":"00068634","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":28.79,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":204,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZnQAO","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":73,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000966vQAA","sfdcName":"PORT ROYAL 15G ORIG RUM & WINE","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797283847","b2BCCProductCategory":"RYO","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075076853","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":26},"shortDesc":"PORT ROYAL 15G ORIG RUM &amp; WINE","id":"a6w8E000000966vQAA","sku":"10065881","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":15.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PA","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"PORT ROYAL 15G ORIG RUM & WINE","price":28.79}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000966vQAA","ccrz__SKU__c":"10065881"}}},{"s":74,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZmQAO","sfdcName":"00068633","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":28.79,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":202,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZmQAO","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":75,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000966cQAA","sfdcName":"PORT ROYAL 15G HIGHLAND WHISKY","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797283861","b2BCCProductCategory":"RYO","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075079687","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":23},"shortDesc":"PORT ROYAL 15G HIGHLAND WHISKY","id":"a6w8E000000966cQAA","sku":"10041618","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":3.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PA","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"PORT ROYAL 15G HIGHLAND WHISKY","price":28.79}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000966cQAA","ccrz__SKU__c":"10041618"}}},{"s":76,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZlQAO","sfdcName":"00068632","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":41.92,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":199,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":1.30,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":2.30,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZlQAO","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":77,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096BgQAI","sfdcName":"HOLIDAY 25G BRIGHT BLUE","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797281669","b2BCCProductCategory":"RYO","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075025968","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":38},"shortDesc":"HOLIDAY 25G BRIGHT BLUE","id":"a6w8E00000096BgQAI","sku":"10088017","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":25.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PA","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"HOLIDAY 25G BRIGHT BLUE","price":41.92}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096BgQAI","ccrz__SKU__c":"10088017"}}},{"s":78,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZkQAO","sfdcName":"00068631","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":26.51,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":195,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.00,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZkQAO","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":79,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096BhQAI","sfdcName":"CAPSTAN 15G MAKERS BLEND","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797285476","b2BCCProductCategory":"RYO","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075087239","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":41},"shortDesc":"CAPSTAN 15G MAKERS BLEND","id":"a6w8E00000096BhQAI","sku":"10088018","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":15.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"PA","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"CAPSTAN 15G MAKERS BLEND","price":26.51}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096BhQAI","ccrz__SKU__c":"10088018"}}},{"s":80,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZFQA4","sfdcName":"00068600","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":188.56,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":12,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":2.50,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":4.10,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":4.20,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZFQA4","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":81,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000965pQAA","sfdcName":"B&H 30/120 SMOOTH BLUE","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797285537","b2BCCProductCategory":"TMC","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075089380","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":20},"shortDesc":"B&amp;H 30/120 SMOOTH BLUE","id":"a6w8E000000965pQAA","sku":"10086360","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":120.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"CT","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"B&H 30/120 SMOOTH BLUE","price":188.56}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000965pQAA","ccrz__SKU__c":"10086360"}}},{"s":82,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZEQA4","sfdcName":"00068599","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":188.56,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":11,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":3.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":4.00,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":4.60,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZEQA4","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":83,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E00000096BVQAY","sfdcName":"B&H 30/120 CLASSIC RED","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797285520","b2BCCProductCategory":"TMC","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075089380","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":35},"shortDesc":"B&amp;H 30/120 CLASSIC RED","id":"a6w8E00000096BVQAY","sku":"10086472","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":120.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"CT","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"B&H 30/120 CLASSIC RED","price":188.56}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E00000096BVQAY","ccrz__SKU__c":"10086472"}}},{"s":84,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZDQA4","sfdcName":"00068598","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":330.53,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":9,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.50,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.90,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.90,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZDQA4","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":85,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E0000009632QAA","sfdcName":"B&H 25/200 FINE GREY FF","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797002615","b2BCCProductCategory":"TMC","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075001150","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":14},"shortDesc":"B&amp;H 25/200 FINE GREY FF","id":"a6w8E0000009632QAA","sku":"10014887","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":200.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"CT","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"B&H 25/200 FINE GREY FF","price":330.53}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E0000009632QAA","ccrz__SKU__c":"10014887"}}},{"s":86,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZBQA4","sfdcName":"00068596","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":1,"price":330.53,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":330.53,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":6,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":0.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":0.30,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":0.50,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZBQA4","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":87,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000962OQAQ","sfdcName":"B&H 25/200 SMOOTH DRK BLUE FF","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797002516","b2BCCProductCategory":"TMC","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075001150","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":5},"shortDesc":"B&amp;H 25/200 SMOOTH DRK BLUE FF","id":"a6w8E000000962OQAQ","sku":"10014748","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":200.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"CT","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"B&H 25/200 SMOOTH DRK BLUE FF","price":330.53}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":330.53,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000962OQAQ","ccrz__SKU__c":"10014748"}}},{"s":88,"v":{"sfid":"a5w8E000000LFZAQA4","sfdcName":"00068595","cart":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","quantity":0,"price":330.53,"productType":"Product","storeID":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","pricingType":"auto","itemTotal":0.00,"cartItemType":"Major","itemStatus":"Available","b2BCCSubAmountDiscount":0.00,"b2BCCIsFeatured":false,"b2BCCIsStrategic":false,"b2BCCSequence":5,"b2BCCPromotionTotal":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSC1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSM1":0.00,"b2BCCPromotionZSP1":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowPrice":0.00,"b2BCCPromoCappingOverflowQty":0,"b2BCCAvgSales4Weeks":1.00,"b2BCCAvgSales8Weeks":1.60,"b2BCCAvgSales13Weeks":2.10,"sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"AUD","itemID":"a5w8E000000LFZAQA4","cartId":"a5x8E000000ICRBQA4","showSubProdTerm":false,"mockProduct":{"s":89,"v":{"sfid":"a6w8E000000962YQAQ","sfdcName":"B&H 25/200 CLASSIC RED FF","ownerId":"0058E000007MQgfQAG","storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","startDate":1577836800000,"endDate":7258032000000,"averageRating":0.00,"taxable":false,"inventoryType":"STANDARD","b2BCCBarcode":"9310797002011","b2BCCProductCategory":"TMC","b2BCCSTMCode":"000000000075001150","sfdcCurrencyISOCode":"GBP","EProductMediasS":{"r":8},"shortDesc":"B&amp;H 25/200 CLASSIC RED FF","id":"a6w8E000000962YQAQ","sku":"10014816","ProductType":"Product","ProductStatus":"Released","qtyPerUnit":200.000000,"UnitOfMeasure":"CT","showSubscriptionSelection":false,"name":"B&H 25/200 CLASSIC RED FF","price":330.53}},"qtyIncrement":1,"SubAmount":0.00,"adjustment":0,"baseDiscount":0,"absoluteDiscount":0,"product":{"Id":"a6w8E000000962YQAQ","ccrz__SKU__c":"10014816"}}}]},"cartItemCount":1}},"inputContext":{"currentCartId":"b86853d1-2929-44bb-84de-826bb350ff59","currentPageName":"ccrz__ProductList","currentPageURL":"https://batuat-batglobalb2b.cs87.force.com/B2BAUSECOMMERCE/ccrz__ProductList?effectiveAccount=0010Y00001cdP0yQAE&refURL=https%3A%2F%2Fbatuat-batglobalb2b.cs87.force.com%2FB2BAustraliaCommunity%2Fs%2F","effAccountId":"0010Y00001cdP0yQAE","portalUserId":"","priceGroupId":"","queryParams":{"s":90,"v":{}},"storefront":"B2BAUSECOMMERCE","userIsoCode":"AUD","userLocale":"en_US"},"messages":{"s":91,"v":[]},"success":true}}]
```

Below is the code in Jmeter for the steps I have mentioned above

```java
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

String Path = "\\\\fjsvdishares\\85039042\\Documents\\2021\\J-Meter\\data.csv";


try 
    {
                      
           
         String test = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(Path));
           
                Map map = new HashMap();

        map.put(vars.get("SKU"),vars.get("quantity"));
             
    
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();                 
            JSONArray cartItemsList = null;
            JSONObject cartItemsObj = null;

                    

             String jsonString = vars.get("C_Totalresponse");

         
         JSONObject cartItemsObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
         SONArray cartItemsList = (JSONArray) cartItemsObj.get("cartItems");
          
          
            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext() ) {

                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                
                if(cartItemsList.size() > 0 ) {  

                    for(int i = 0; i < cartItemsList.size(); i++){

                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) cartItemsList.get(i);

                        JSONObject productJsonObj = (JSONObject)object.get("product") ; 
                        
                        

                        if( productJsonObj.get("ccrz__SKU__c").toString() .equals(pair.getKey().toString()) ) {   

                            object.put("quantity" , pair.getValue()); 
                        }

                        
                          
                    }
                }
                    
            }
           
                   
       }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error details are below :

> 2021-03-17 07:42:03,146 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
> javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult; import org.apache.jmeter.threads . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : at Line: 48 : in file: inline evaluation of:` import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult; import org.apache.jmeter.threads . . . '' : ( JSONObject ) jsonParser .parse ( jsonString )

> Target exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.json.simple.JSONArray to org.json.JSONObject
> in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult; import org.apache.jmeter.threads . . . '' at line number 48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many posts for Beanshell processor code to read data from haspmap and use hashmap to update data in json request array values. Many people have suggested to use groovy\JSR223 processor. Here is the code below in beanshell which will be helpful to many users whose requests\questions we left unanswered.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;  
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


String Path = "\\\\fjsvdishares\\Documents\\2021\\J-Meter\\data.csv";


try 
    {
                      
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Path));
               Map map = null;
               Map map = new HashMap(); //Creating hashmap
             String line =  null;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){  //writing data into hashmap from csv file
        
               StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ","); 
               
                       while ( st.hasMoreElements() ){
                        
                          String key = st.nextToken();
                            String value = st.nextToken();
                            map.put(key,value);
                       
                         }
  
                    } 
          
        
         
           String jsonString = vars.get("C_cartItems"); //reading json request into string          
         
           
               //code to fetch skus in request and update the quanity for the select sku 
          
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonString); 
        
            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            int count =0;
            while (it.hasNext() ) {
                //Getting the first pair values from map object
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();

                if(jsonArray.length() > 0 ) {
                    //Iterating through the cartitem list
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        //Getting the first cartlist item
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject insideVObject = (JSONObject)object.getJSONObject("v") ;
                        JSONObject productJsonObj = (JSONObject)insideVObject.getJSONObject("product") ;

                                                    
                        
                       //Checking the Sku value from cartitem and map
                        if( productJsonObj.get("ccrz__SKU__c").equals(pair.getKey()) ) {      
                            //updating the quantity value with new value
                            object.put("quantity" , pair.getValue()); 
                            count++;
                        }
                          
                    }
                }
                    
                
            }   

           // log.info(count + " ...items updated");
           // log.info(" resultJson   ...." +jsonArray);
          
                   
       }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is problematic (at least)

```
JSONObject cartItemsObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString)
```

I believe you need to change it to:

```
JSONArray cartItemsObj = (JSONArray ) jsonParser.parse(jsonString)
```

I cannot comment further on your code because your JSON is not valid and it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.

With regards to using Groovy - this is something you should really consider because:

1. [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
2. [Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
3. [Groovy is more compatible with Java and supports all modern Java runtime features](https://www.infoq.com/articles/groovy-3-new-features-java/)

Comment: I have changed the code to some extent  

     JSONArray cartItemsObj = (JSONArray ) jsonParser.parse(updatedjsonString);

     int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("cartItemsObj") );  

     log.info("Beanshell"+count);

    JSONObject cap = (JSONObject) cartItemsObj.get(1);

But I am not getting the count of array information log viewer when I execute it

Comment: I see below is code culprit causing the problem 
 [{\"remainingQuantity\":-48,\"description\":\"BENSON & HEDGES 20 CIG\",\"code\":\"000000000075001149\"}] this automatically generated in response